# Four first columns linearly independent of a binary matrix

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I have a binary matrix A of size `4x7`. I want to create a Matlab function that determines if the first four columns of the matrix are linearly independent if not permute to find the first four linearly independent columns and the other three columns will follow.

For example : if the first three columns and the fifth columns are linearly independent, then the new matrix will give the first, second, third and fifth columns and the last three columns will be the fourth, sixth and seventh column of A.

Example :

```
A = [1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1;0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1;0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0;0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1];
```

The first three columns of A are linearly independent, the fifth colomn is linearly independant of the first three colomns. 
we find

```
B = [1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1;0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1;0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0;0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `A` is `4x7` you can find the solution in the following:

```
  A = randi(1, 4, 7); // replace real A here
  p = perms(1:7);
  for i = 1:length(p)
      newA = A(:,p(i,:));
      if(rank(A(:,1:4)) == 4)
          break;
      end
  end
  result = newA;
```

Comment: First thanks for your code.But if the four columns of the matrix A are independent the function must return the same matrix A. And the permutation of the columns to have the four independent columns to be ordered.If A = [1 0 0 1 1 0 0; 0 0 0 1 0 1 1; 0 0 1 0 1 0 1; 0 1 0 1 1 0 1] you program return result = [0 0 1 1 0 0 1; 1 1 0 1 0 0 0; 1 0 1 0 1 0 0; 1 0 1 1 0 1 0] while the first four columns of A were already linearly independent.

Comment: I want If a have matrix A = [1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1;0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1;0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0;0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]  the program will just swap columns 4 and 5 (because the first four columns of A are dependent) to give a new matrix B = [1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1;0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1;0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0;0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1] and if the four first columns of A are independent the program juste return the matrix A.

Comment: If you see the result of the `perms`, it's started by the ordered permutation like [1 2 3 4 5 6 7].